# References needed for gradient flow

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, gradient-flows

Can anyone recommend lecture notes or (not too obscure) books that teaches me about gradient flow and what it has to do with PDEs? I did search but usually the material talks about dynamical systems which I don't want too much of. Something understandable by someone that knows about basic parabolic existence results would be good, and something that doesn't require knowledge of Riemannian geometry.

Thanks.

Comment: Evans Partial differential equations

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

- Chapter 13 of [Lectures on Optimal Transport](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-72162-6) by Luigi Ambrosio, Elia Brué, and Daniele Semola.

You could also consult

- Section 3.2 of the very new book [An Invitation to Optimal Transport, Wasserstein Distances, and Gradient Flows](https://ems.press/books/etb/190) by Alessio Figalli and Federico Glaudo,
- Sec. 8 of [Optimal transport for applied mathematicians](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-20828-2) by Filippo Santambrogio
- Sec. 2.1 of [$\{$Euclidean, metric, and Wasserstein$\}$ gradient flows: an overview](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13373-017-0101-1) by Filippo Santambrogio,
- [Variational Modelling: Energies, gradient flows, and large deviations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.1990) by Mark A. Peletier

as well as [this talk by Katy Craig](https://simons.berkeley.edu/talks/tbd-335) (from 31:28 onwards), [this lecture by Brittany Hamfeldt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzGBxAqJV0Q&ab_channel=BrittanyHamfeldt).

Other standard (but more advanced) references are [Optimal Transport - Old and New](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-71050-9) by Cedric Villani and [Gradient flows: in metric spaces and in the space of probability measures](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b137080) by Luigi Ambrosio, Nicola Gigli, and Giuseppe Savarè.