# A good introduction to gradient flows?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation, gradient-flows

I would like to learn more about gradient flows and their application to the theory of PDEs. I was wondering if anyone had any favourite texts that they thought provided a good and solid introduction to the topic?

There is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154324/references-needed-for-gradient-flow) which was asked in 2012. They seemed to recommend the text Partial Differential Equations by L. Evans.

I ask the question again because it hasn't received a great deal of attention and also there may be more modern texts available now which give an introduction to gradient flows.

Thanks for any recommendations given.

EDIT: I realise there is the book by Gigli et al. which discusses gradient flows on metric spaces. I would prefer to work with something describing the theory on $\mathbb{R}^n$ if such a text was available. However it may be the case that this book simply is the best resource out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the Bible of Gradient Flows, the book "Gradient Flows: In Metric Spaces and in the Space of Probability Measures" by Luigi Ambrosio, Nicola Gigli, and Giuseppe Savare

Comment: Are gradient flows inherently based in probabily measured spaces?

Comment: Hi Fei, thanks for your answer. My knowledge of probability measures is somewhat rudimentary. I would prefer it if there was a text concerned with discussing grad. flows on $\mathbb{R}^n$ if you know of such a reference. Have you read parts of this book yourself?

Comment: The book is comprehensive and covers a lot of things (maybe more than what you need) about gradient flows), and it starts with the gradient flows on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I have just read a few chapters on it.